# Converting regions/subdivisions (from FIPS to ISO 3166 or vice versa )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, region, geo, country-codes

I have two databases, one with country and subdivisions (states/regions) and one with cities.

The problem is, that they use both a different norm.

The Countries subdivisions delivers: ISO 3166-2 Codes (Numbers and Characters) and
the Cities Subdivisions uses FIPS (only Numbers).

**Where or how can I match them together?**

Are there available "Mappers?

**Germany Example:**

**Subdivision:** Brandenburg

- ISO 3166-2 -> BB
- FIPS -> 11

Example Dataset:

**Country / Subdivisions:**

```
{"alpha2"=>"DE",
 "alpha3"=>"DEU",
 "name"=>"Germany",
 "names"=>["Germany", "Deutschland", "Allemagne", "Alemania", "ドイツ", "Duitsland"],
 "number"=>"276",
 "subdivisions" => {
    "BB"=>{"name"=>"Brandenburg", "names"=>["Brandenbourg", "Brandenburgo"]},
    "BE"=>{"name"=>"Berlin", "names"=>["Berlín"]}, 
    "BW"=>{"name"=>"Baden-Württemberg", "names"=>["Baden-Württemberg", "Baden-Wurttemberg"]},
    "BY"=>{"name"=>"Bayern", "names"=>["Bavière", "Bayern", "Bavaria"]}, 
    "HB"=>{"name"=>"Bremen", "names"=>["Brème"]},
    "HE"=>{"name"=>"Hessen", "names"=>["Hessen", "Hesse"]},
    "HH"=>{"name"=>"Hamburg", "names"=>["Amburgo", "Hambourg", "Hamburgo"]},
    "MV"=>{"name"=>"Mecklenburg-Vorpommern", "names"=>["Mecklenburg-Vorpommern"]},
    "NI"=>{"name"=>"Niedersachsen", "names"=>["Niedersachsen"]},
    "NW"=>{"name"=>"Nordrhein-Westfalen", "names"=>["Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Rhénanie-Westphalie"]}, 
    "RP"=>{"name"=>"Rheinland-Pfalz", "names"=>["Rheinland-Pfalz", "Rhénanie-Palatinat"]},
    "SH"=>{"name"=>"Schleswig-Holstein", "names"=>"Schleswig-Holstein"}, 
    "SL"=>{"name"=>"Saarland", "names"=>"Saarland"},
    "SN"=>{"name"=>"Sachsen", "names"=>["Sachsen"]},
    "ST"=>{"name"=>"Sachsen-Anhalt", "names"=>"Sachsen-Anhalt"},
    "TH"=>{"name"=>"Thüringen", "names"=>["Thüringen", "Thuringen"]}}}

 {"alpha2"=>"AT",
 "alpha3"=>"AUT",
 "name"=>"Austria",
 "names"=>["Austria", "Österreich", "Autriche", "オーストリア", "Oostenrijk"],
 "number"=>"276",
 "subdivisions" => {  
    "1"=>{"name"=>"Burgenland", "names"=>"Burgenland"}, 
    "2"=>{"name"=>"Kärnten", "names"=>["Carinthia", "Koroška"]},
    "3"=>{"name"=>"Niederösterreich", "names"=>["Lower Austria"]}, 
    "4"=>{"name"=>"Oberösterreich", "names"=>["Upper Austria"]},
    "5"=>{"name"=>"Salzburg", "names"=>["Salzbourg"]},
    "6"=>{"name"=>"Steiermark", "names"=>["Styria"]},
    "7"=>{"name"=>"Tirol", "names"=>["Tyrol"]}, 
    "8"=>{"name"=>"Vorarlberg", "names"=>"Vorarlberg"}, 
    "9"=>{"name"=>"Wien", "names"=>["Wien", "Vienna"]}}}
```

**Cities:**

```
{"country_code"=> "DE",
 "region" => "11", 
"name" => "Brandenburg"}

{"country_code"=> "AT",
 "region" => "5", 
"name" => "Salzburg"}
```

many, many, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to map it yourself. This is my list:

https://gist.github.com/ducfilan/19818937a864f4ca2459b6e74db41f1a